# Filtering in admin broken for custom post type in 3.8.1?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

Is there a known issue with the All, Published, Scheduled and Drafts filters in the post listing page for custom post types for 3.8.1? The links update as well as the URL, but the listing doesn't refresh.

It even appears that the query isn't paging as well.

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme.

Comment: @kaiser i traced it to my theme. what are common ways that a theme could break this? it does not define the same post type that i am defining in my plugin

Comment: Filter callbacks/actions that work on stuff like `pre_get_posts`, `parse_query`, etc.